# Jest it.each - This expression is not callable. Type 'String' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs

I am trying to use the [describe.each`table`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#2-describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) using TypeScript but am receiving "error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type 'String' has no call signatures."

Here is my code:

```
  it.each(
    `field       |      expectedMessage
    ${"username"} | ${"Username cannot be null"}
  `(
      "returns $expectedMessage when $field is null",
      async ({ field, expectedMessage }) => {
           ...
       )
  );
```

In VSCode, here is how the error looks:

[image]
I don't know how to type this to fix the error because the syntax is a bit weird to me.

I tried to type It like this following the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#template-literal):

```
it.each(<{field: string; expectedMessage: string}>
    `field       |      expectedMessage
    ${"username"} | ${"Username cannot be null"}
  `(
```

But it only got worse:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo, try

```
it.each`
    field         | expectedMessage
    ${'username'} | ${'Username cannot be null'}
`('returns $expectedMessage when $field is null', async ({ field, expectedMessage }) => {
    // ..
    console.log(field, expectedMessage);
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
});
```

Or, pass generic parameters to `test.each` explicitly:

```
import { test } from '@jest/globals';

test.each<{ field: string; expectedMessage: string }>`
    field         | expectedMessage
    ${'username'} | ${'Username cannot be null'}
`('template literal example', ({ field, expectedMessage }) => {
    // without the generic argument in this case types would default to `unknown`
});
```

package version:

```json
"@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
"typescript": "^5.1.3"
```